# Laravel get data from dropdown list and pass it to the controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to have the user choose a month from a dropdown list displaying the months, and passes that month value (in numbers) to the controller
I am having trouble making the dropdown list an action so once the user picks the month, the controller gets called.

here is my index page:

```
  <h>Display a logs by monthly <h>
    {{ $id=Form::selectMonth('month')}}
    <a href="{{action('LogController@monthly',['id' => $id]) }}"  class="btn btn-primary">Monthly Logs
      </a>
```

and when I add the Form method inside the  tag i am getting an error says the variable is not defined.

here is the Controller.php

```
 public function monthly($id)
 {
     $dcmlogs = log::with('users')
     ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', $id)
     ->paginate(15);
    return view('dcmlog.index', compact('dcmlogs'));
}
```

Comment: You need to  be a bit more specific. What is your actual problem? Do you already have the DropDown working? And is the dropdown already changing the URL correctly? Is your controller function called or not? I am not sure what your problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['logs', $id], 'method' => 'POST' ])!!}
  {{ Form::select('in_out',[1 => 'Jan', 2 => 'Feb'] , null, ['class'=>' 
     form-control']) 
  }}                 
{!! Form::close() !! }}
```

hope this helps ..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creatintg a route

```
Route::get('/logs/{id}', 'LogController@monthly')->name('logs');
```

And use the route function in the template:

```
route('logs', ['id'->$id]);
```

Comment: I already have specific route for that page, but my problem is when the user is in the main page, he's faced with a dropdown list, this list contains the months, once a month is picked. the user is routed to logs/monthly/{id} . but I can't figure out how to capture the selected month and send it to the controller.

Comment: Hav eyou tried <a href="{{route('logs', ['id'->$id]);}}">Monthly logs</a>  ?